# Entity Framework Linq two tables together with formatting

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm quite stuck with Entity Framework and how things work. In most cases I can suffice with a following method that returns a List and I can bind it to something like a DropDownList:

```
    public static List<Data.Land> GetLandList()
    {
        List<Data.Land> ListEntities = null;

        using (Data.languagesEntities context = GetDbContext())
        {
            ListEntities = (from ent1 in context.Land
                            orderby ent1.Land_sortering ascending, ent1.Land1 ascending
                            select ent1).ToList<Data.Land>();
        }

        return ListEntities;
    }
```

But for another DropDownList I needed to "Linq" two tables together AND concat values from serveral tablecells to get the desired Text I wanted to show. I ended up with this hidious piece of code I can't extract into a method:

```
public class DropdownDisplay
{
public string value { get; set; }
public string Text { get; set; }
}

void Input_DropDownList_SelectCourse_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, BootstrapUI.UserControls.BootstrapFormControls.DropDownListItemEventArgs e)
{
    int Cursus_ID = Convert.ToInt16(this.Input_DropDownList_SelectCourse.Value);

    Data.languagesEntities context = Data._languagesEntities.GetDbContext();

    var ListEntities = (from ent1 in context.Cursusdata
                        from ent2 in context.Cursus
                        where ent1.Cursus_ID == Cursus_ID
                        && ent1.Cursus_ID == ent2.Cursus_ID
                        && ent1.Cursusdata_gesloten == 0
                        orderby ent1.Cursusdata_startdatum ascending
                        select new
                        {
                            Cursusdata_ID = ent1.Cursusdata_ID,
                            Cursus_Code = ent2.Cursus_Code,
                            Cursusdata_einddatum = ent1.Cursusdata_einddatum,
                            Cursusdata_startdatum = ent1.Cursusdata_startdatum,
                            Cursusdata_tijden_NL = ent1.Cursusdata_tijden_NL,
                            Cursusdata_tijden_UK = ent1.Cursusdata_tijden_UK,
                            Cursus_ID = ent1.Cursus_ID
                        }
                        ).ToList();

    List<DropdownDisplay> List_DropdownDisplay = new List<DropdownDisplay>();
    foreach (var Entity in ListEntities)
    {
        string newStartDatum = (Entity.Cursusdata_startdatum == null) ? "" : ((DateTime)Entity.Cursusdata_startdatum).ToShortDateString();
        string newEindDatum = (Entity.Cursusdata_einddatum == null) ? "" : ((DateTime)Entity.Cursusdata_einddatum).ToShortDateString();

        List_DropdownDisplay.Add(new DropdownDisplay()
        {
            value = Entity.Cursusdata_ID.ToString(),
            Text =
                Entity.Cursus_Code + " - " + newStartDatum +
                " - " + newEindDatum + " - " + Entity.Cursusdata_tijden_NL
        });
    }

    this.Input_DropDownList_SelectPeriod.DataSource = List_DropdownDisplay;
    this.Input_DropDownList_SelectPeriod.DataValueField = "Value";
    this.Input_DropDownList_SelectPeriod.DataTextField = "Text";
    this.Input_DropDownList_SelectPeriod.DataBind();
  }
```

How should I have done this in a proper manner?

**EDIT: I should clarify my question: t3chb0t's answer does extract my solution in a method, but I also wanted to know how I could improve the data collection and manipulation.**

Many thanks,
Rémy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following:

Just get the Cursus_ID in the first DDL and call an update method for the other DDL:

```
void Input_DropDownList_SelectCourse_SelectedItemChanged(
    object sender, 
    BootstrapUI.UserControls.BootstrapFormControls.DropDownListItemEventArgs e)
{
    int Cursus_ID = Convert.ToInt16((sender as Input_DropDownList_SelectCourse).Value);
    Update_Input_DropDownList_SelectPeriod(Cursus_ID);
}
```

Update the other DDL with a helper method:

```
void Update_Input_DropDownList_SelectPeriod(int Cursus_ID)
{
    List<DropdownDisplay> dropdownDisplayList = GetDropdownDisplayList(Cursus_ID);
    Input_DropDownList_SelectPeriod.DataSource = dropdownDisplayList;
    Input_DropDownList_SelectPeriod.DataValueField = "Value";
    Input_DropDownList_SelectPeriod.DataTextField = "Text";
    Input_DropDownList_SelectPeriod.DataBind();
}
```

Get the data for the other DDL with another helper method:

```
List<DropdownDisplay> GetDropdownDisplayList(Int16 Cursus_ID)
{
    Data.languagesEntities context = Data._languagesEntities.GetDbContext();

    var ListEntities =
        from ent1 in context.Cursusdata
        from ent2 in context.Cursus
        where ent1.Cursus_ID == Cursus_ID
        && ent1.Cursus_ID == ent2.Cursus_ID
        && ent1.Cursusdata_gesloten == 0
        orderby ent1.Cursusdata_startdatum ascending
        select new
        {
            Cursusdata_ID = ent1.Cursusdata_ID,
            Cursus_Code = ent2.Cursus_Code,
            Cursusdata_einddatum = ent1.Cursusdata_einddatum,
            Cursusdata_startdatum = ent1.Cursusdata_startdatum,
            Cursusdata_tijden_NL = ent1.Cursusdata_tijden_NL,
            Cursusdata_tijden_UK = ent1.Cursusdata_tijden_UK,
            Cursus_ID = ent1.Cursus_ID
        };

    List<DropdownDisplay> List_DropdownDisplay = new List<DropdownDisplay>();
    foreach (var Entity in ListEntities.ToList())
    {
        string newStartDatum = (Entity.Cursusdata_startdatum == null) ? "" : ((DateTime)Entity.Cursusdata_startdatum).ToShortDateString();
        string newEindDatum = (Entity.Cursusdata_einddatum == null) ? "" : ((DateTime)Entity.Cursusdata_einddatum).ToShortDateString();

        List_DropdownDisplay.Add(new DropdownDisplay()
        {
            value = Entity.Cursusdata_ID.ToString(),
            Text =
                Entity.Cursus_Code + " - " + newStartDatum +
                " - " + newEindDatum + " - " + Entity.Cursusdata_tijden_NL
        });
    }
    return List_DropdownDisplay;
}
```

---

EDIT:

In the shorter version of the query you can create the `DropdownDisplay` object right away without the intermediate anonymous one:

```
List<DropdownDisplay> GetDropdownDisplayList(Int16 Cursus_ID)
{
    Data.languagesEntities context = Data._languagesEntities.GetDbContext();

    var ListEntities =
        from ent1 in context.Cursusdata
        from ent2 in context.Cursus
        where 
            ent1.Cursus_ID == Cursus_ID
            && ent1.Cursus_ID == ent2.Cursus_ID
            && ent1.Cursusdata_gesloten == 0
        orderby ent1.Cursusdata_startdatum ascending            
        select new DropdownDisplay
        {
            value = ent1.Cursusdata_ID.ToString(),
            Text = String.Format(
                "{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}",
                ent2.Cursus_Code,
                ent1.Cursusdata_startdatum == null ? string.Empty : ((DateTime)ent1.Cursusdata_startdatum).ToShortDateString(),
                ent1.Cursusdata_einddatum == null ? string.Empty : ((DateTime)ent1.Cursusdata_einddatum).ToShortDateString(),
                ent1.Cursusdata_tijden_NL
            )
        };

    return ListEntities.ToList();
}
```

but still the *coolest* way would be to let the `DropdownDisplay` class create the values for its properties based on the data given:

```
public class DropdownDisplay
{
    public DropdownDisplay(EntityType1 ent1, EntityType2 ent2)
    {
        value = ent1.Cursusdata_ID.ToString();
        Text = String.Format(
            "{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}",
            ent2.Cursus_Code,
            ent1.Cursusdata_startdatum == null ? string.Empty : ((DateTime)ent1.Cursusdata_startdatum).ToShortDateString(),
            ent1.Cursusdata_einddatum == null ? string.Empty : ((DateTime)ent1.Cursusdata_einddatum).ToShortDateString(),
            ent1.Cursusdata_tijden_NL
        );
    }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

then the query would be even shorther:

```
List<DropdownDisplay> GetDropdownDisplayList(Int16 Cursus_ID)
{
    Data.languagesEntities context = Data._languagesEntities.GetDbContext();

    var ListEntities =
        from ent1 in context.Cursusdata
        from ent2 in context.Cursus
        where 
            ent1.Cursus_ID == Cursus_ID
            && ent1.Cursus_ID == ent2.Cursus_ID
            && ent1.Cursusdata_gesloten == 0
        orderby ent1.Cursusdata_startdatum ascending            
        select new DropdownDisplay(ent1, ent2);

    return ListEntities.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Dear T3chb0t, yes thx that's the first improvement I should have done: extracting part of the data collection and manipulation out of the form and in a business/data class. But what about the data manipulation and retrieval? Is there no better way of doing this? First of all I don't like to use var's (we have left that behind in Visual Basic 6 to get it back 15 years later). And I don't like to use another loop for manipulation of the data. 
**Sorry I asked my question not clearly**

Comment: There is a _better_ way or a little shorter one. See my edited answer. I added another example how it could be done (there can by a typo as I cannot compile it).

Comment: Whoohoo... I can live in peace again with Entity Framework using "the coolest way" to do it! Thx t3chb0t!